# Supported filetypes for bzip2

Tags: python, compression, bzip2

Is possible to compress all  type of files using bzip2?

I'm trying to write python bzip2 realization (Burrows-Wheeler Transform + move2forvard) and now can only compress .txt (string) files.

Comment: You should be able to compress all types of regular files. It may fail for special files like character files on linux. What problem are you having? Share some code. Files should be open in binary mode so that python doesn't attempt to convert them to text.

Comment: Please try and you will find out more

Comment: @tdelaney answer with open in binary mode help me to solve the problem. Many thanks!